# Unable to compensate for the time difference while accessing mysql

Tags: android, mysql, momentjs, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I store date time in google cloud **mysql** as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I access using `momentjs` with `knex` **typeCast:** option (Nodejs server hosted in Google App Engine) and convert them to milliseconds before sending response back to client (android).

Real date in database: **2019-01-07 12:37:48**

What Android gives when I convert the date to MYSQL date format: **2019-01-07 15:37:48**
Note the difference of 3 hours.

How I convert in android:

```java
public static SimpleDateFormat DB_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
  public static SimpleDateFormat DB_FORMAT_UNCHANGED = new 
  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  "updated_at", > DB_FORMAT_UNCHANGED.format(milliseconds);
  "updated_at", > DB_FORMAT_UNCHANGED.format(milliseconds);//giving similar inaccurate result
```

**Question:** How can I solve this in a way that wont mess the accuracy of date wherever my app users travel to across the world since **subtracting the +3 GMT offset is not efficient**

**EDIT:**
How it's converted during access in the server, inside`knex config`:

```js
const config = {
        user: 'user' ,
        password: 'pwpw' ,
        database: 'dbdb'  ,
        typeCast: function (field, next) {
            if (field.type === 'JSON') {
                return (JSON.parse(field.string()));
            }
            if (field.type === 'TINY' && field.length === 1) {
                return (field.string() === '1');
            }
            if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
                return (moment(field.string()).valueOf());
            }
            return next();
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you are using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` then you are producing and recording the timestamp in the MySQL database, not in the client application. Is that right? If that's the case, then the timestamp does not depend on the client. If that's the case, then the problem is when you read the data.

Comment: Yes, I don't want my app time to depend on the client since that can be manipulated or can be inaccurate, I want to do that on server side and that's why I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or SYSDATE

Comment: You might also want to add `timezone : 'utc'` attribute to your connection attributes (It won't fix your issues though). You could use `TIMESTAMP` type instead of `DATETIME` to get have your times interpreted always with timezone and not treated as local times of the client's timezone.

Comment: That's right @MikaelLepistö, I just realized that `moment.valueOf()` is the problem while `moment.unix()` give the right value, compiling a solution, you may also organize this and post as a solution, I'll mark it right.

Comment: Meaning the problem was in the way I converted time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL returns `DATETIME` column values without timezone offset. So when client interprets them they will be read as local time of client's timezone.

You could use `TIMESTAMP` column type instead to get have your times interpreted always with timezone and to get always consistent value for the unix timestamp even if client's timezone differs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the server is generating a timestamp in "some" time zone, probably local to it. Your client application is not aware of it. That server time zone may even change in the future. Even if it does not change, it may be subject to daylight saving time variations.

Using `CURRENT_TIMESTAP` is great to make sure the database is always recording the correct value. However, in later queries, when you need to filter data by it, your application must be aware of the time zone to send the proper values in the query.

MySQL `DATATIME` and `TIMESTAMP` data types do not have alternative variations `WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. You seem to need this kind of data type, that other databases offer.

Considering this, the solution I see is that you set the time zone to a specific one at configuration time and convert accordingly. That is, the **server** and the **app** should use the same one all the time. And yes, I know that's not what you want, but you'll need to perform the time zone conversion each time.

In some ORMs, you can intervene the "type converter" in order to perform the conversion automatically on every insert/update/delete/select. Maybe you have this option to avoid changing all your code.

Comment: A great piece here, I think I may need to do the conversion manually though I need to look at the internals of `momentjs` ; Look at the edit in the question.